# Android Firebase- Not getting all keys as a list, what should I do?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get list of all keys in recyclerview, tried everything but getting nothing, I do not want attributes of keys. Once I get a list of all keys in recyclerview then I will make it clickable and then I want attributes of that key which is clicked please help my this my Final year Project.

I did not use the method setFname of my POJO class because I put my data manually in Firebase.

[image]

[image]

```
package com.fyp.phasse_4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class foodBasketFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<FoodsModel> foodsModels;
private DatabaseReference foodRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String currentUserID;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
String p;


public foodBasketFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container,         
@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_basket, container, false);
    foodRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FoodData");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FoodsModel model = new FoodsModel()
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    foodsModels = new ArrayList<>();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FoodsModel>()
            .setQuery(foodRef, FoodsModel.class)
            .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FoodsModel, myViewHolder> adapter = new     
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FoodsModel, myViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, final int position, 
@NonNull final FoodsModel model) {

            foodRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    }
                    holder.name.setText();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.foods_list, parent, 
false);
            return new myViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();


}
public static class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView name;
    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    }
}

}
```

This is my POJO class,

```
package com.fyp.phasse_4;
public class FoodsModel {
public String fName;

public FoodsModel() {
}
public FoodsModel(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

public void setfName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}
}
```

Comment: I would like to recommend you to use pushKey() instead normal String.

Comment: Please show us the content of one of those two objects. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry I didn't get it which two objects?

Comment: In the screenshot. In that red rectangle.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated my question kindly check it.

Comment: Something is not correct. In the screenshot, you have 5 properties while in the `FoodsModel` class you have only one. Make me understand what exactly you need, as it is unclear now.

Comment: @AlexMamo Actually I want to make a list in recyclerview in which I want 1-Beans and Peas, 2-Lentils, cooked as a list, I do not want those 5 attributes

Comment: To understand correct, you first need a list with only two items, correct? And you made a class for that, named  `FoodsModel `. Then according to what is clicked, you need to display the values of those 5 items, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Exactly Now you got it brother please help me.

Comment: This is really a bit too broad to reasonably be able to answer on Stack Overflow. You should shard this into small pieces and do it one by one.

Comment: @AlexMamo It is solved now Thanks for your help brother.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     String key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
     System.out.println(key);
}
```

Comment: getting 1-Beans and peas, Lentils cooked, 2-Beans and peas, Lentils, Cooked

Comment: U getting both the keys twice?

Comment: Yes I don't know why :-(, It takes all keys as one String and since I have 2 keys in firebase so that's why it shows twice

Comment: that's strange.. because when I try it in my system, it's showing the correct output.. no. of keys printed = no. of keys in the database

Comment: Why are you initializing the recycler view inside onStart()? Try putting your entire recyclerview code inside the onCreateView() method.. your onStart() should have adapter.startListening(); only.. override onStop() method also

Comment: I did that but still same issue, twice. by the way can you show me screenshot of yours?

Comment: brother are you using custom MyAdapter or FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211660/discussion-between-syed-zaidi-and-mayur).